# What does $f(x,y) = y' = \frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}$ mean? $\partial_x f(x,y)$ or $\partial_y f(x,y)$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

I'm a little unsure about this case but curious to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither $\partial_x f(x,y)$ nor $\partial_y f(x,y)$. I imagine that the context is the one of ODE.

And you're looking to find $y(x)$ as a map of $x$. You just want to have at any point $x$ the derivative $y^\prime(x) = \frac{dy}{dx}(x)$ to be equal to $f(x,y(x))$.

Comment: yea, you've darted right, it's about ODE

Comment: But I'm still a little confused. Because furthermore it says "$\left(\begin{array}{c} \Delta x\\ \Delta y \end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{c} \Delta x\\ f(x,y)\,\Delta x\end{array}\right)$". So it's being claimed that $\Delta y = f(x,y)\,\Delta x$ what I would just tolerate if $f(x,y)$ = $\partial_x f(x,y)$ since in one dimensional space: $\Delta y = f'(x)\,\Delta x$

Comment: You would have $\Delta f = f(x,y) \Delta x$ in the case of $\partial_x f(x,y)$. Not  $\Delta y = f(x,y) \Delta x$.

Comment: Ah, thank you for pointing out that difference, understood!